# Complex inequalities and constants

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analyticity

Let $f(z)$ be an analytic function. Show that if $|f(z)| > 1 + |e^z|$ then $f(z)$ is constant.

I have no idea what to do, I've subbed $z= x+iy$
and got $|f(z)|>1+e^x$
 but lost here.

Comment: $f$ is analytic in where ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Presume that $f$ is entire.

Comment: It is necessary to mention that $f$ is entire OR $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb C$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Clearly $f$ has no zeros. Then

$$\left|\frac{1 + e^z}{f(z)}\right| < 1$$
for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. What can you conclude now?

---

Alternatively, if you prefer even stronger theorems, note that $f(\mathbb{C})$ is missing two points.

Comment: All too easy.  +1 for the concise and solid hint!

Comment: Sorry friend, I have not seen anything like that before. I see how you got to that but I don't know what to conclude after a bit of fiddling with that. Though I also know it must be greater than 0.

Comment: @@ Cayde) Do you know Liouville's theorem ? Picard's little theorem ??

Comment: Oh, actually, yes. I'll need to revise it though. I'll respond soon, and thanks!

Comment: Alright so, can I say this? Let $g(z) = $ the function above which is less than 1. It is bounded and entire so by theorem, it is constant. Would this be sufficient?

Comment: @Cayde Yes, but you should specifically cite the theorem you use (in this case, Liouville).

Comment: Oh alright, thanks. I am curious about your stronger theorems method, how does that go?

Comment: @Cayde [Little Picard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) shows that the image of a non-constant entire function is either $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ minus a single point. The image of $f$ is missing infinitely many points, namely anything in the unit disk.

Comment: That Picard's little theorem..which states ' An entire function which omits at least two values is necessarily constant'. In this case f omits $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote down the theorems for future reference. Y'all are life savers. Oh 1 final thing, if $g(z)$ is constant, does it imply, $f(z)$ is as well?